# Saving and Viewing/Editing data in Android

Tags: java, android, save

I have been working on an app that can save your passwords for you. I would like it to work similarly to a contacts application. For example, I want to have a screen that displays all the names of the passwords entered *(like the names of your contacts)*, then when you click on the name, it takes you to a screen with all the information you previously entered on it *(like the phone numbers/email addresses that would be in your contacts)*. I also would like a way to edit this information. I have been searching for almost 2 weeks now and have found nothing to help me. If someone could simply point me in the right direction, or tell me what this way of saving information would be called so I can research it, it would be GREATLY appreciated. If possible, could any answers be explained well enough that a fairly new developer could understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a **ListView** and some **Adapter** to show the name of the password, and when you click one of them, you create an **Intent** which leads you to a new **Activity** which show the associated details. In the detail **Activity** you can do some editing job and save them to database or **ContentProvider**. 
If I am right, I think you need to follow the tutorial of Android development to learn more about Android system.

Comment: Thanks for you're help! Do you think a SQLite Database would work to save the information?